# jQuery: conditionally executing without "if"

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery or javascript to ignore all operations if the wrapped sets size is 0 withoug using if statement.

```
 menu.find('a[href="#add"]'). {code that should execute only if size()>0};
```

I guees I would normally have to do something like this

```
var m = menu.find('a[href="#add"]');

if m.size()>0 { do something }
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Edit: full code

```
menu.find('a[href="#add"]').attr("href","#add-metaobject")[0].innerText = "Add Object";
```

Comment: Bleh, don't use innerText! You're using jQuery for the selection so keep with it! Use something like $(this).html('Add Object');

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, as far as javascript, I am just like blind person looking for a light switch.

Comment: Epitka, please see the last addition to my solution.

Comment: Thanks you guys, with this I was able to finish combining treeview plugin with context menu plugin. I love jQuery!!!

Comment: epitka, take a few minutes to look around the jQuery API.  Their documentation is *really* well setup, such that you can skim through it and learn most of the important things in just a few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the selector finds 0, it doesn't matter what follows it.

```
$(".nonExistentElement").css("color","red"); // nothing will be red
```

This is the case with `$.each()` too

```
$(".nonExistentElement").each(function(){
  World.technology.push(new PerpetualMotionMachine);
  // too bad this block will never take place
});
```

You could use a ternary operator, but it is really just another conditional check:

```
$("#someEl").length ? alert("found") : alert("not found") ;
```

Comment: This is true for chained operations but arbitrary code doesn't work the same.

Comment: The edited code sample has an array index. The specific problem is use of `innerText` instead of `text()`.

Comment: menu.find('a[href="#add"]').attr("href","#add-metaobject").text("Add Object");

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Missunderstood the original question, but on your sample code you can just chain the operations as Jonathan suggests:

```
menu.find('a[href="#add"]').attr("href","#add-metaobject").find(":first").text("Add Object");
```

Comment: This is the same as `….size()`.

Comment: That is exactly what I don't want to do, I do not want to wrap it in bunch of ifs. I guess I need null propagation in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're operating on each individual object found, you could use the `.each()` method which will not execute if no items were found:

```
menu.find('a[href="#add"]').each(function() {
  // do stuff... 
});
```